# Laravel 3 and static?

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

So, I have a lot of stuff like this in my models:

```
public function can_reply($user)
{
 if($user->banned == 0) return 1;
 return 0;
}
```

And when I want to use them in my models, I have to use stuff like:

```
 $post = new Post;
 if($post->can_reply($user))
 {
  //do something
 }
```

Why am I not able to use this?:

```
   if(Post::can_reply($user))
```

It looks nicer and stuff.
Am I doing something wrong? Should I use something else for methods like can_reply, parse_text, is_banned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try making the method `static` in your model:

```
public static function can_reply($user)
{
 if($user->banned == 0) return 1;
 return 0;
}
```

Now you can use it like `if(Post::can_reply($user)) { /*do somethig*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access a method in a static way as you wish, you need to define the method as static:

```
public static function can_reply($user)
{
    if ($user->banned == 0) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```